# How to understand this CSS inheritance (or override, selection)

Tags: html, css, fonts, css-specificity

[image: From Chrome DevTool]

I'm creating a Jekyll web page forked from [Pixyll](https://github.com/johnotander/pixyll). First, I'm really new to CSS and anything related to HTML.

Please refer to the screen capture. The bigger picture is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecGnc.png), and the HTML/CSS parts are in the below. Everything is just as is, except for the red boxed content.

[image]

The original theme has the same styles for the title "Awesome title" and "About | Contact". **I want to modify the weight and font face of the site tile only.**

The original HTML has `site-title` class for "Awesome title", but the CSS doesn't have specialized one for `site-title` class.

I added `.site-title` as shown in the red box. I was able to override font-family, font-size, and spacing, but the color and weight were inherited from `.site_header`. From my programming background, "Awesome title" has the nearest `site-title` CSS while `.site_header` is at the outer scope.

Questions:

1. Why the outer `site-header` shadows the inner definitions of `site-title`?
2. What would be the most elegant way to define its own font color etc to the site title?

Comment: More specific selectors overwrite less specific ones. To read more about selector specificity in the official specification by the W3C, **[CSS Selectors Specification: Specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity)**.

Comment: No answer picked yet. Is your problem solved or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I believe html tags take precedence over css classes. So a  css definition will trump a .site-title css class definition.
2. You can try being a little fancier and combining the two..

   ```
   header .site-title {
     color: ;
     font-weight: ;
   }
   ```

this is just saying that whenever there is a site-title in a header, do this css.

Comment: `header.site-title` won't find any elements according to OPs html structure. Did you by any chance mean `header .site-title`?

Comment: @connexo Correct. There must be a space between `header` and `.site-title`. `header .site-title` works, too.

Answer (score -1):

The reason is that in the more specific definition `.site-header a` both a class **and** and element are involved, whereas in `.site-title` only a class is involved.

Use `a.site-title` instead and it should work as long as your definition comes after the one your want to override in the CSS source order.

This illustrates how it is calculated by the browser:

> http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html

[image: CSS Specificity Calculation]

Comment: Glad I could help. Remember to mark the answer (click the checkmark left of it).

Comment: If the person who downvoted this correct answer would be so kind to explain what they have to criticize?